# Seleccionar match1 en regex con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy aplicando una expresión regular a un código HTML, y ahora mismo estoy haciendo este código:

```
regEx = /(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])/;
linkNoticia = noticias.match(regEx);
```

Pero me guarda en la variable linkNoticia todas las coincidencias del regex.

¿Como puedo hacer para que me seleccione solo el Match1?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bienvenido a la comunidad. Te cuento un poco acerca del método [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) de **javascript**, este mismo nos permite, como dice en su documentación dentro de [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/):

> El método match() se usa para obtener todas las ocurrencias de una
> expresión regular dentro de una cadena.

Bien hasta ahí, pero debes ponerle mucha atención a lo siguiente, cito:

> Si la expresión regular no incluye el **flag g**, devuelve el mismo
> resultado que [Regexp.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).
>
> Si la expresión regular incluye el **flag g**, el método devuelve un Array
> que contiene todos los emparejamientos.

El uso de la [**bandera**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#b%C3%BAsqueda_avanzada_con_banderas) `g` dentro de las **regex** nos ayuda a encontrar patrones de manera global, por ejemplo, que no se detenga en la primera coincidencia.

Entonces usar el método [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) sobre una expresion que no la contenga, no tiene mucho sentido, ya que sus valores devuelto seran:

1. En el índice `[0]` la primera coincidencia
2. En el resto de los índices, una clase de metadatos referentes a tu cadena

Lo mismo que hace [`Regexp.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec); lo que puedes hacer para obtener lo que buscas es, traer siempre el primer indice del resultado y ademas usar la bandera `g` para ahorrarte esos datos que no necesitas:

```js
regEx = /(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])/g;

// Observa el [0] al final de la expresión
linkNoticia = noticias.match(regEx)[0];
```

---

##### NOTA

Puedo ver que tu **regex** es algo complicada y tal vez se pueda simplificar algo más obteniendo el resultado que buscas, si editas tu pregunta y nos das a entender que patrón quieres obtener quizá podamos mejorarla un poco ;)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu comentario, me ha ayudado mucho!

Comment: Un placer..!! recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada si soluciono tu problema, así se dará como finalizada la pregunta